# How to replace one image with another in jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am designing a progress bar which is having 9 images. Initially those should be unfilled. Based on the status i need to replace them with the filled images(I have both filled and unfilled images for progress bar).
Can anyone help me with my problem.

Here is my code in view which displays unfilled images:

```
<div id="ProgressBar" style="text-align: center">
        <img id="imgArrow1" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/left_filled.png")" />
       @* <label class="Pbar">
            <img id="imgArrow2"  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/middle_unfilled.png")" />
            <img id="imgArrow3"  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/middle_unfilled.png")" />
            <img id="imgArrow4"  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/middle_unfilled.png")" />
            <img id="imgArrow5"  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/middle_unfilled.png")" />
            <img id="imgArrow6"  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/middle_unfilled.png")" />
            <img id="imgArrow7"  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/middle_unfilled.png")" />
            <img id="imgArrow8"  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/middle_unfilled.png")" /></label>*@



         <label class="Pbar"><img id="imgArrow2"  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/middle_unfilled.png")" /></label>
           <label class="Pbar">  <img id="imgArrow3"  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/middle_unfilled.png")" /></label>
          <label class="Pbar">   <img id="imgArrow4"  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/middle_unfilled.png")" /></label>
          <label class="Pbar">   <img id="imgArrow5"  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/middle_unfilled.png")" /></label>
          <label class="Pbar">   <img id="imgArrow6"  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/middle_unfilled.png")" /></label>
          <label class="Pbar">   <img id="imgArrow7"  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/middle_unfilled.png")" /></label>
           <label class="Pbar">  <img id="imgArrow8"  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/middle_unfilled.png")" /></label>

        @if (Model.loanTrackerResults.loanStatus == "Funded")
        {
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/right_filled.png")" />
        }
        else
        {
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/right_unfilled.png")" />
        }
    </div>
```

Here is my Jquery code

```
 $("#ProgressBar").ready(function () {
            var la = document.getElementsByClassName('Pbar');
            alert(la);
            console.log(la);
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                @*  //la[2].attr('src', '~/Content/img/middle_filled.png');
                $("#Pbar").replaceWith('<img src = "@Url.Content("~/Content/img/middle_filled.png")" />');*@

                la[i].attr('src', '~/Content/img/middle_filled.png');                
            }
        });
```

Comment: `$("#Pbar")` selects `id="Pbar"`. You should probably use `$(".Pbar")` which selects `class="Pbar"`

Comment: @DanielLisi: yes, ijust need to replace the unfilled with filled ones.

Comment: @MagnusEngdal: i commented out that line as it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have been trying to fix a lot while leaving all the non working code around. It seems to be quite a lot you don't need there anymore?

I'm not sure exactly what it is you are trying to do, but if you want to loop through each `Pbar` while replacing the `middle_unfilled` with `middle_filled`, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $('.Pbar').eq(i).html('<img src="/Content/img/middle_filled.png" />');               
    }
});
```

Note that this will go so fast that every image will be replaced almost instantly.

It's also much easier to loop through every `Pbar` with `.each()`, but I take it you want to make some progress function so I left the `for` in there.

Here you have the same thing with `.each()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.Pbar').each(function() {
        $(this).html('<img src="/Content/img/middle_filled.png" />');
    });               
});
```

Neither of these looks like a progress bar to me, but hopefully you have some pointers in here to help you progress.

Comment: I need to replace images based on the status code. Suppose it is 5 then i need to replace unfilled with filled for only those 5 images. rest of them should be unfilled only. That's why i'm using the for loop.

Comment: I treid that it didn't make any difference. The images are still unfilled only. Can you tell me whether i need to use label with in the DIV tag?

Comment: I updated my answer with some modifications that should work to get you started. You should probably also replace your `<label>` elements with something else, like `<div>` for example. This probably isn't the place to use `<label>`. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: I used the for loop from yours but it is not working.

Comment: Can´t believe I didn't notice it before. `@Url.Content` doesn't work on the client, only when it's sent to the server. You need to put the actual path to `/Content/img/middle_filled.png` inside the loop when replacing the images since `@Url.Content` won´t work there.

Comment: Updated the path in my answer to only say `"/Content/img/middle_filled.png"`. That needs to be a direct link to where where the image is located.

Comment: I tried that one too, but the image didn't get replaced. Just want to let you know that $('.Pbar') is the label class id not the div id

Comment: Yes, and it's the html inside the label that is replaced.

Comment: but its not replacing with the new image source. I also tried this.attr('src', <'<img src="/Content/img/middle_filled.png" />') that one also didn't work. Is there any other way to get an image with in jquery

Comment: If i tried to update based on individual image id then i'm able to replacing that image. I cannot replace them based on the label id.